# Enum failing == when value retrieved via reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I am trying to implement a custom jQuery Unobtrusive Validation attribute for MVC 6.  Below is the `IsValid()` implementation for an attribute that looks at an adjacent property in a class and compares it to a compile-time constant.

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    ValidationResult result = ValidationResult.Success;

    // Simplest case, there is something in this field
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value?.ToString()))
        return result;

    // Check relative field
    try
    {
        // Grab the property referenced via reflection
        var relativeProperty = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(this._relativePropertyName);

        // Compare the runtime value of that property to the Attribute initialized value
        if (relativeProperty.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance) == this._relativeValue)
        {
            // Fail if those 2 values are equal
            result = new ValidationResult(this.ErrorMessageString); 
        }

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        result = new ValidationResult(this.ErrorMessageString);
    }

    return result;
}
```

For the most part, this works exactly as expected.  The only issue I am having is when the property referenced and its value are a derivative of an Enum (for example, let's pretend our enum is `Result`).  Implementing this attribute would look like the following in a class:

```
public class TestObject
{
    public Result TestResult { get; set; }
    [IsEqual(nameof(TestResult), Result.Pass)]
    public string PassComment { get; set; }
}
```

When the debugger gets to the line `if(relativeProperty.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance) == this._relativeValue)` it fails, even if `relativeProperty.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance)` resolves as `Result.Pass`.  Using the Immediate Window, `relativeProperty.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance)` = `Result.Pass` and  also `this._relativeValue` = `Result.Pass`

Small side note, calling `.GetType()` on both values are also equal.

I'm assuming this has something to do with boxing, but can't pinpoint it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to give a bit more information, including the signature of the attribute and its constructor (what is `_relativePropertyName` and `_relativeValue` and how your setting them)

Comment: They are set in the constructor of the attribute as demonstrated in the example class `TestObject` above.

Comment: No, I mean the code for the attribute - the signature of your `IsEqualAttribute` and its constructor

Comment: It appears your trying to compare `enum` values but your have not cast the value to an enum (your comparing an `object`)

Comment: You do realize that the name MVC 6 has been dead for a couple of years now, don't you? If you are talking about ASP.NET Core, then you have the wrong tags. If you are talking about MVC 5 then you have the wrong version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `==` to evaluate equality for things that aren't strongly typed. Consider the following:

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(((object)Result.Pass) == (object)Result.Pass);
    // False

    Console.WriteLine(((object)Result.Pass).Equals((object)Result.Pass));
    // True

    Console.WriteLine(object.Equals((object)Result.Pass,(object)Result.Pass));
    // True
}

public enum Result{
    Pass, Fail
}
```

In C#, the `==` operator can be overridden to make syntax easier when comparing certain types of objects, which has the advantage of providing compile-time errors if you try to `==` two incompatible types. And some people think it looks nicer.

However, when values are down-cast to `object`s, the `object == object` operator performs an `Object.ReferenceEquals()` check. Since enums are Value Types, they have to get "boxed" into a new object in order to be cast as `objects`, and those new objects are going to exist in different memory locations. Hence, `ReferenceEquals()` will be false.

Instead, use the `object.Equals()` method, which passes to the individual class's `.Equals()` override. In this case, the Enum type's override of `.Equals()` will check whether the value can be cast to a `Result`, and whether the resulting value is the same as `this` one's.

The advantage to `object.Equals(value1, value2)` over `value1.Equals(value2)` is that you don't get a null exception if `value1` is null.

Comment: Thanks for this!  I assumed it was something along these lines.  Changed the code to use `.Equals()` and it works fine.

Comment: @jeff17237: See my update. You might want to use `object.Equals(x, y)` instead to avoid exceptions if you encounter a null value.